Why MongoDB connection fails when running backend in Docker container on AWS Lightsail
On AWS Lightsail, I am trying to establish communication between the backend and the database containers.
Here is my setup:

However, the result is different from my test on the local machine.
docker-compose.yml on local machine:
services:
  database:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo_database
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password123
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - backend_network

  backend:
    image: custom_backend:latest
    container_name: backend_service
    environment:
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://username:password123@database:27017/
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - backend_network

networks:
  backend_network:
    driver: bridge

This setup runs successfully on my local machine.
Lightsail's backend log from Open log↗ (ERROR):
[8/Jul/2024:15:00:15] [deployment:1] Creating your deployment
[8/Jul/2024:15:01:21] Running the application...
[8/Jul/2024:15:01:49] [deployment:1] Started 1 new node
[8/Jul/2024:15:02:45] Running the application...
[8/Jul/2024:15:03:25] [deployment:1] Health checks failed: port 4000 is unhealthy
[8/Jul/2024:15:03:46] make: *** [Makefile:3: run] Terminated
[8/Jul/2024:15:04:58] [deployment:1] Took too long
[8/Jul/2024:15:06:01] make: *** [Makefile:3: run] Terminated

localhost's log (SUCCEED):
backend$ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container mongo_database   Started                                                                                                                                                 0.2s 
 ✔ Container backend_service  Started  
backend$ docker compose logs backend
backend_service  | Running the application...
backend_service  | INFO 2024/07/08 15:30:48 Starting server on http://localhost:4000
backend_service  | 2024/07/08 15:30:50 [0165dc51d9d0/fprkUHXqaT-000001] "GET http://localhost:4000/ HTTP/1.1" from 172.18.0.1:36804 - 200 25B in 35.389µs

I also see no networks or depends_on options on Lightsail. I am not sure if that is causing this issue, but I couldn't find those configurations on the Lightsail dashboard.

Can you turn off the healthcheck, and then go check the Docker container manually? If Lightsail is just an EC2 machine, can you get an SSH session on that box, then exec bash on the running container within?
